# Running module from ipython interpreter instead of command line

Tags: python, package, ipython

I'm working on a package, and I have a structure like:

```
 mypackage/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    someotherstuff.py
    test/
        __init__.py
        testsomeotherstuff.py
```

I've set it up so that the **main**.py function runs some unit tests, and executing `python mypackage` from the command-line works fine. However often I want to debut using ipython, but from the interpreter, `run mypackage` gives the error `ERROR: File 'mypackage.py' not found`. I can run it manually by doing `run mypackage/__main__.py` but somehow this seems wrong. Is there something else I should have done to set this up correctly?

Comment: The ability to do `%run -m mypackage` was added in a recent version - I don't know if that works for your case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running a package as a program was introduced in Python 2.5.  I don't think IPython has a native feature for this, but starting with version 2.7, the Python standard library has, namely the [`runpy.run_module()`](http://docs.python.org/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_module) function.  Note that this behaves slightly different than IPython's `%run`, since it will return the global dictionary of the module instead of directly importing it into the interpreter scope.

Comment: That gives me an error: `ImportError: mypackage is a package and cannot be directly executed`

Comment: @tdc: What Python version are you using?

Comment: `Python 2.6.5` - which makes it odd that it runs from the command line then?

Comment: In Python 3.11 I do `runpy.run_module("mypkg.my_module", run_name=__name__)` to run the code inside the `__main__` section of a submodule. I cannot manage to pass arguments (in sys.argv), though

Comment: @JuanPi Modules look at `sys.argv` themselves for their command line options. Since this is where they look, you need to modify `sys.argv` before calling `run_module()` to pass in arguments. This isn't the prettiest thing to do, since you pass parameters via global state, but in general the only alternative is forking a new interpreter.